# Is there a way to refer to the current model's _id field during validation in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, validation, mongoose, unique

I have a schema. And the only prescription, is a uniqueness validation.

```
User.path("email").validate(hasUnique("email"), "uniqueness");
```

`hasUnique` returns the function that will be used by `mongoose` to validate the uniqueness of the value.

```
function hasUnique(key) {
  return function(value, respond) {
    var query = {};
    query[key] = /A regex used to look up the email/;

    User.findOne(query, function(err, user) {
      respond(!user);
    }
  }
}
```

This works well when a new document is created. But when I query a document, mutate an attribute then call `save`, this validation gets called and fails because it sees its own email in the collection and thinks this isn't unique.

Is there a way I can exclude the document itself in the validation function returned from `hasUnique`? My thought is that I can add a $not predicate to exclude the current doc's _id field in the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Mongoose validation function, `this` is the document being validated.

So you could do:

```
function hasUnique(key) {
  return function(value, respond) {
    var query = { _id: { $ne: this._id }};
    query[key] = /A regex used to look up the email/;

    User.findOne(query, function(err, user) {
      respond(!user);
    }
  }
}
```